# Invalid attempt to call MetaData when reader is closed version2

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, metadata

I have a template of sqlconnection, and I have use this code before there was no problem. Until i want to use it in datagridview.

```
   private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow != null)
        {
            try
            {
                SQLConn.sqL = "SELECT ProductID,PCode,PName FROM Products WHERE PCode='" + txtBarcode.DataGridView.CurrentCell.Value.ToString() + "'";
                SQLConn.ConnDB();
                SQLConn.cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLConn.sqL, SQLConn.conn);
                SQLConn.dr = SQLConn.cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (SQLConn.dr.Read())
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value = SQLConn.dr["ProductID"].ToString();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value = SQLConn.dr["PName"].ToString();


                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Interaction.MsgBox(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                SQLConn.cmd.Dispose();
                SQLConn.conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think multiple calls getting in this function for that event which causing the issue. Please add SQLConn.dr.Close() to close open reader in finally clause.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: https://ibb.co/s9W5RmW

Answer (score 0):

I think multiple calls getting in this function for that event which causing the issue. Please add SQLConn.dr.Close() to close open reader in finally clause.

Comment: I have try it. However, Im still getting this error message.
https://ibb.co/s9W5RmW

Comment: one more possibility is reader do not have data, so check if rows are there in reader by using,
if (SQLConn.dr.HasRows)
{
}

Comment: it still the same error.Actually the result of the output is what I like to happen. just don't want to let user see the popup message.